# Loading of data in combo box is slow using jsp

Tags: jsp

I have 3 combo boxes created in jsp which are linked and the data is populated from database.
But the loading of data on combo box is slow as data is loaded from remote server.
Are there any way to sort this problem.
I have used code similar to the link below.
http://www.roseindia.net/answers/viewqa/JSP-Servlet/21391-jsp-combobox.html

Comment: Code sample please. Don't see any links 'below'.

Comment: thanks i forgot to post the link

Answer (score 0):

Bad performance on this particular case can have many possible causes, the most important being:

- DB table is not properly indexed. Make sure that colums which are involved in WHERE are indexed.
- SQL query is inefficient. Explain/Analyze the query using the DB specific tool and improve it.
- The DB connection is recreated for every single query. Use a decent connection pool.
- The query returns thousands of rows. Use a filtering/autocomplete dropdown instead.

As an alternative, if the data is rather static and not extraordinary large, you could load it once and keep in application scope and if necessary run a scheduled task to refresh it hourly or so.